# Determine which tab is active from the controller

Tags: forms, cakephp, tabs, cakephp-3.x

Good Morning (or afternoon). I have a form that contains several tabs (organized sections) and then an edit button. What I want to do is, EDIT the information based on the active tab (Tombstone/Sales/Dates). How do I pass to the controller the active tab and then redirect to the proper Template?

[Section to Edit](http://newconnections-ministries.org/images/tabsactivated.jpg)

I hope you can see the link. I was not able to add an attachment.

Comment: I can envision a few possible page layouts that could match your description, and they have different solutions. Any chance you can add a screenshot to show what you mean?

Comment: @GregSchmidt Thank your giving a hand, hope we can find some sort of solution. i was not able to add an attachment but I added a link to an image in the question.

Comment: Okay, you're going to need some JavaScript. I'm no expert in that, so I can't give an exact answer, but I think an `onClick` handler for the Edit button which queries the DOM to see which tab is active and changes the URL that it's going to open based on that.

Comment: You are correct. It needs to be done via JS but since it is a government application we are not allowed to use JS. There is no way this can be achieved without that. At least that is what i know. Thank you Greg! it was worth the try.

Comment: If you can't use JS, how is the tabs UI implemented?

Comment: CSS wet-boew - I guess this is the framework they use. Do you know if there is a way to review the attributes of a DIV from the Controller?

Comment: The DOM is a client-side thing. The controller is server-side.

Comment: Absolutely correct and without JS there is no way we can achieve this. Need to bring it up in the next scrum meeting. No JS no feature, simple as that... Thank you for your help.